# Orthogonal projection in Hilbert Space proof

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading Brezis (Functional Analysis) and in Corollary 5.4 "Assume that $M \subset H$ is a closed linear subspace. Let $f \in H$. Then $P_{M}f$ is characterized by
$$u \in M \text{ and } (f-u,u)=0 \ \forall v\in M$$
Proof:
We have
$(f-u,v-u)\leq 0 \ \forall v\in M$
and
$$(f-u,tv-u)\leq 0\ \forall v\in M, t\in \mathbb{R} \tag{$*$}$$ 
Its follows that $u \in M\ \text{and} \ (f-u,u)=0 \ \forall v\in M$ holds.
I don't see why $(*)$ implies what I need, any help?

Comment: Page 8 of these notes
https://team-pancho.github.io/teaching/math806/Hilbert.pdf
has a very nice introduction to the orthogonal projection, with the proofs done in a bit more detail.

Comment: Nice set of notes!

Comment: How does Brezis define $P_M f$?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think:
$$t(f-u,v)\leq (f-u,u)\ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$
But $(f-u,u)$ is fixed, so if $t\neq 0$ that implies that $(f-u,v)$ must be equals to $0$.
Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.